# How to calculate and format time using Python

Tags: python, time

To get the current time...

current_time = f"Time now:{time.ctime()}"

...and the output is:

Time now:Thu Feb 22 10:35:01 2024

I want to now add on a set number of hours (e.g. 3, 5 hours), and use the same format as above (instead of 'Time now', 'Expires')

Any advice?

I tried to convert the hours to seconds, then add it to 'time.time()', then pass it through 'time.ctime()'. However, this comes up with this error:

OverflowError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t

Comment: Show the code that you've tried…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `time` package is mostly for timestamps. What you want is probably `datetime`, that includes easy-to-use functions to add hours.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

future = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=3)
print(future.ctime())
# Thu Feb 22 14:50:54 2024
```